# WordPress does not load jQuery

Tags: functions, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to use WordPress with Bootstrap but WordPress does not load jQuery properly so I get this error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery. jQuery must be included before Bootstrap's JavaScript.

This is from my functions.php:

```
function add_theme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap', 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_theme_file_path() . '/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('Popper', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('Bootstrap', 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery', "Popper"), null, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('script', get_theme_file_path() . '/assets/js/script.js', array('jquery', 'Popper', 'Bootstrap'), null, true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_theme_scripts');
```

Could you please help me with this issue? Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Have you directly confirmed that jQuery is not loaded? ignore bootstrap and open the browser dev tools and try to use jQuery directly, e.g. enteriing `jQuery` in the dev console and pressing enter. if it returned `undefined` then it isn't loaded. You can also look at the source code to check if jQuery's JS file is present, and the network tab. Don't rely on bootstrap to check, it may be incorrect

Comment: Yes, I tried that: ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Comment: And does your theme or a plugin elsewhere attempt to deregister and re-register jQuery so that it uses a CDN?

Comment: No, it does not. It's really weird. :(

Comment: As Tom also said, can you try looking at your page in view-source mode to find the script tag where it is trying (and presumably failing) to include jQuery? If it's there, can you look at the Network tab in your browser's debug tools to see if the file loaded properly: was there an error, and what is it, or if there was no error can you check that the server response for that file looks right, i.e. like a version of jQuery?

Comment: Or if it's not there, try changing your `wp_enqueue_script('jquery');` line to add a path to jQuery from a CDN, to see if that'll fix it. If it does then something has unregistered jQuery somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me. It was a stupid mistake on my side. I forgot to add a default case to my add_script_attributes function.

Comment: jQuery should be a part of WP, lots of WP Admin parts depend on it

Comment: I don't think this is an issue with jQuery loading itself but rather that some of the code you're using in your `assets/js/script.js` are using `jQuery` as and identifier when it's not supposed to and it's treating it as a javascript variable.

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to add a default case to the switch...case statement of my add_script_attributes function in the functions.php file. Sorry that I did not see this before.

From my functions.php:

```
function add_script_attributes($tag, $handle) {
    switch($handle) {
        case "Popper":
            return str_replace("src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js'", "src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js' integrity='sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo' crossorigin='anonymous'", $tag);
        case "Bootstrap":
            return str_replace("src='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js'", "src='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js' integrity='sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI' crossorigin='anonymous'", $tag);
        default:
            return $tag;
    }
}
add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'add_script_attributes', 10, 2);
```

Comment: What's "a default case"?

Comment: This answer doesn't make sense, and refers to code that isn't in the question, can you edit it to include examples?

Comment: @JacobPeattie The default code block from a switch statement.

Comment: @TomJNowell Sorry, I've added the code snippet to the answer now. My functions.php is very long, and I did not think that this snippet would be relevant. That's the reason why I did not add it to the question.